# Using jqPlot to make Charts in an Android WebView

Tags: javascript, android, webview, jqplot

I'm using jqplot to show graphs in android, it works fine for some devices and works half the time in others (ex : Samsung galaxy ace and Nexus 5, ...)

I think it's a javascript memory leaks, and I don't know how can I fix it...

Any suggestions and answers are welcome

Thank you

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't found a solution to fix that, I lost a lot of time without results.
I think the best solution is to use a natif charts library [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart)
It's a very powerful library, very easy to use and we can do anything with. I recommend it to any android developer.